# Delphi : thread safely suspend in excute module

Tags: delphi, thread-safety

I am a beginner of DELPHI.
I have to develop a application based on thread.
How can I suspend thread in thread execute function, not in UI thread....
Please give me sample

Answer (score 1):

Suspend a thread simply by pausing. For instance you can sleep for a specified amount of time. Or you can wait on a synchronisation object. For instance, you might wait on an event. When another thread signals that event, the paused thread will resume.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working on Windows platform...

There are many ways to suspend a thread. Which one to use depends largely on when/why it should resume, and whether or not the thread has a message queue.

The point about the message queue is especially important if you need to suspend a thread for a long time. Any thread not processing Windows message can hang many operations, DDE communications, message broadcast, etc. The contract being "If your thread has a message queue, it NEEDS to treat them.", and it needs to do so in a timely fashion. In this case, I would suggest calling `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` from the thread. The function works even if you are not waiting on any objects, which allows you to both wait on messages and have a timeout. `WaitMessage` could work too, but it doesn't timeout which has, amongst other implication, that you would need to send a message to the thread after terminating it, otherwise, it might never terminate.

If the thread does not have a message queue, then there are plenty of options. `Sleep` is a valid one if you want to wait for a specific amount of time. If you want to wait for a specific event to resume the thread, the `TEvent` class might be what you are looking for.

Hard to give a definitive answer without more details.

Comment: If you need to wake up to process messages, then wait for an event with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`

Answer (score -1):

This example runs OK. By working with threads, by very careful.  This is a very difficult section.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyThread=class(tthread)
  FEvent:THandle;
  private
  procedure SetText;
  protected
  procedure Execute;override;
  public
  constructor Create(CreateSuspended:Boolean=false);
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure Start;
  procedure Stop;
  procedure StopAndTerminate;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    OutMem: TMemo;
    BtnStart: TButton;
    BtnStop: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  mythread:tmythread;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mythread:=tmythread.Create();
end;

{ TMyThread }

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  Inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FEvent:=CreateEvent(nil,true,false,pchar(inttostr(handle)));
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  CloseHandle(FEVENT);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not terminated do
  begin
    WaitForSingleObject(FEvent,INFINITE);
    if terminated then exit;
    Synchronize(SetText);
    { Methods and properties of objects in visual components (forms, buttons, memo and other)
     can only be used in a method called using Synchronize}
 end;

end;

procedure TMyThread.SetText;
begin
  form1.OutMem.Lines.Append(inttostr(gettickcount));
  application.ProcessMessages;
  // Application.ProcessMessages method must be call ONLY in MainThread.
  // by using Synchronize, SetText procedure will be run in MainThread.
end;

procedure TMyThread.Start;
begin
  SetEvent(FEVENT);
end;

procedure TMyThread.Stop;
begin
  ResetEvent(FEVENT);
end;

procedure TMyThread.StopAndTerminate;
begin
  Terminate;
  PulseEvent(FEVENT);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mythread.StopAndTerminate;
  mythread.WaitFor;
  mythread.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mythread.Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.BtnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  mythread.Stop;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You should pass NULL for the name of the event. You should not be calling ProcessMessages here.